# Hibernate One-To-Many join on two columns

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a SQL query that closely resembles the following:

```
select *
from parent p inner join child c on p.id = c.parent_id and c.type = 'PARENT_TYPE';
```

I am trying to define my entity mappings with a @One-To-Many association so that I can load the parent object and it will automatically load the children. The thing I don't know how to do, is how to properly annotate my entities for this to happen correctly with the second part of the join criteria (i.e. `the c.type = 'PARENT_TYPE'` part). I tried using a [@FilterDef](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html)
and then enabling the filter on the session and it worked, but it doesn't seem like the optimal solution.

Comment: Hrmm, looks like [@JoinFormula](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/JoinFormula.html) would work, but I am only on hibernate 3.4.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a join-formula, you will lose other abilities (such as sub-select query fetch optimization). Why aren't the two columns you are joining on part of a key. Introduce an embedded-id type consisting of the two columns and join using that type.